# SUM of COUNTs in the same table

Tags: postgresql, count, sum

I'm doing many counts that I want to show in a table. And I want in the same table to show the sum of all counts.

Here's what I got (simplified - I got 6 Counts):

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NB_book
>
>            item as a1, metadatavalue as m1, metadatavalue as m12, 
>
>                         WHERE m1.field_id = 64 (because I need that field to exist)
>
>                         AND m2.field_id = 66
>
>                         And m2. = book
>
>                         AND a1.in_archive  = TRUE )
>
>                         (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NB_toys
>                          metadatavalue as m1, metadatavalue as m12, 
>                          WHERE m1.field_id = 64 (because I need that field to exist)
>                          AND m2.field_id = 66
>                          And m2. = toys
>                          AND a1.in_archive  = TRUE)
>   )

Now, I want the display to be like

-------------table ----------
|NB_book  | NB_Toys   | total_object |
-----------------------------
|    12       |      10      |      22        |

Comment: I don't understand your problem, your query has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    sum(CASE WHEN condition_1 THEN 1 END) AS firstcount,
    sum(CASE WHEN condition_2 THEN 1 END) AS secondcount,
    sum(thecolumn) AS total
FROM ...
```

Your example query is too vague to construct something usable from, but this'll give you the idea. The conditions above can be any boolean expression.

If you prefer you can use `NULLIF` instead of `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END`. I prefer to stick to the standard `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to figure out what you actually want.  You can run completely different queries that each return a one-row result and combine the results like this:

```
select 
   (select count(*) from pgbench_accounts) as count1, 
   (select count(*) from pgbench_tellers) as count2 ;
```

But perhaps you shouldn't do that.  Instead just run each query by itself and use the client, rather than the database engine, to format the results.